# Can't get Rails foundation abide to work with text_field_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, zurb-foundation

On my form tag I have this:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :update_quantity}, {"data-abide" => ''}) do %>
```

My text field tag:

```
<%= text_field_tag "updated_quantity#{line['id']}", "#{line['Quantity']}", required: true, pattern: 'integer' %>
```

All the javascript is enabled but it doesn't validate the field. The outputted html for the text field is this:

```
<input id="updated_quantity64" name="updated_quantity64" pattern="integer" required="required" type="text" value="1" />
```

I'm thinking it's not working because required="required" should just be required according to the documentation.. any ideas?

Comment: Your example works fine for me with latest Foundation 5. Suggest you construct a JSFiddle or similar that illustrates the problem. Eliminate the Rails helpers and make sure you get the  raw HTML working, and then adjust your rails code to generate the same HTML.